# Why is iterating through flattened iterator slow?

Tags: performance, scala, collections, jmh

```
Scala 2.11.8
```

I'm measuring iteration through flattened and non-flattened iterator. I wrote the following benchmark:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
class SerializeBenchmark
  var list = List(
    List("test", 12, 34, 56),
    List("test-test-test", 123, 444, 0),
    List("test-test-test-tes", 145, 443, 4333),
    List("testdsfg-test-test-tes", 3145, 435, 333),
    List("test-tessdfgsdt-tessdfgt-tes", 1455, 43, 333),
    List("tesewrt-test-tessdgdsft-tes", 13345, 4533, 3222333),
    List("ewrtes6yhgfrtyt-test-test-tes", 122245, 433444, 322233),
    List("tserfest-test-testtryfgd-tes", 143345, 43, 3122233),
    List("test-reteytest-test-tes", 1121145, 4343, 3331212),
    List("test-test-ertyeu6test-tes", 14115, 4343, 33433),
    List("test-lknlkkn;lkntest-ertyeu6test-tes", 98141115, 4343, 33433),
    List("tkknknest-test-ertyeu6test-tes", 914111215, 488343, 33433),
    List("test-test-ertyeu6test-tes", 1411125, 437743, 93433),
    List("test-test-ertyeu6testo;kn;lkn;lk-tes", 14111215, 5409343, 39823),
    List("telnlkkn;lnih98st-test-ertyeu6test-tes", 1557215, 498343, 3377433)
  )

  @Benchmark
  @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
  @BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
  def flattenerd(bh: Blackhole): Any = {
    list.iterator.flatten.foreach(bh.consume)
  }

  @Benchmark
  @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
  @BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
  def raw(bh: Blackhole): Any = {
    list.iterator.foreach(_.foreach(bh.consume))
  }
}
```

After running these benchmarks several times I got the following results:

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
SerializeBenchmark.flattenerd  avgt    5  10311,373 ± 1189,448  ns/op
SerializeBenchmark.raw         avgt    5   3463,902 ±  141,145  ns/op
```

Almost 3 times difference in performance. And the larger I make the source `list` the bigger performance difference. Why?

I expected some performance difference but not 3 times.

Comment: `flattenerd` Don't be a bully. Nerds are people, just like you. ;)

Comment: Well... `Iterator[A]` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html) does not have a `flatten` method. Which means one of the in scope implicits is lifting it to something which provides `flatten` (may include a lot of GC) and then back to `Iterator`

Comment: Also... don't use something like 5 iterations. try something like 1000 to get average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-ran your test with a bit more iterations running under the `hs_gc` profile.

These are the results:

```
[info] Benchmark                                                       Mode  Cnt        Score          Error  Units
[info] IteratorFlatten.flattenerd                                      avgt   50        0.708 â–’        0.120  us/op
[info] IteratorFlatten.flattenerd:â•–sun.gc.collector.0.invocations    avgt   50        8.840 â–’        2.259      ?
[info] IteratorFlatten.raw                                             avgt   50        0.367 â–’        0.014  us/op
[info] IteratorFlatten.raw:â•–sun.gc.collector.0.invocations           avgt   50        0                     ?
```

`IteratorFlatten.flattenerd` had an average of 8 GC cycles during the test runs, where `raw` had 0. This means that because of the noise generated by the allocation by `FlattenOps` (the wrapper class and it's method, particularly `hasNext` which allocates an iterator per list), which is what is needed in order to provide the `flatten` method on `Iterator`, we suffer in running time.

If I re-run the test and give it a minimum heap size of 2G, the results get closer:

```
[info] Benchmark                   Mode   Cnt        Score           Error  Units
[info] IteratorFlatten.flattenerd  avgt   50        0.615 â–’         0.041  us/op
[info] IteratorFlatten.raw         avgt   50        0.434 â–’         0.064  us/op
```

The gist of it is, the more you allocate, the more work the GC has to do, more pauses, slower execution.

Note that these kind of micro benchmarks are very fragile and may yield different results. Make sure you measure enough allocations for the stats to become significant.

Comment: Are you sure that the source is the allocation of `FlattenOps`? Even if it is not optimized away, it should only increase GC load by a factor of 2 comparing to `list.iterator` call. I think the crucial difference is that `flatten` has to allocate inner `iterator` for each inner list, while `foreach` doesn't. So it might be interesting to compare `flatten` with  `list.iterator.foreach(_.iterator.foreach(bh.consume))` with additional inner `_.iterator` call

Comment: @SergGr When I meant `FlattenOps` I really meant the entire wrapper for `Iterator`, not just the allocation of the class (which isn't a value class, I don't see it being optimized away). I'd put my money on: `def hasNext: Boolean = it.hasNext || its.hasNext && { it = its.next().toIterator; hasNext }` which allocates an iterator per inner list.

Comment: Yuval, this is exactly what I meant in my comment and this is why I suggested additional test with additional `_.iterator` inner call. I believe that if your diagnosis that the difference is mainly from the GC is right, current wording of your answer is misleading. It probably should be "_noise generated by the allocation **by** (or **inside**) FlattenOps_" instead of "_noise generated by the allocation **of** FlattenOps_"

Comment: @SergGr Thank you for you comment. I've updated the answer.